# Creating a conditional column on a table T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

I have a table called dbo.asientti. Inside, there is a column called `"D/H"`. It contains identifiers: `"D"` for debit, and `"H"` for credit. On another column I have the debit and credit amount. The `"D/H"` column tells me if the amount is a credit or a debit.

What I want to do is separate them: that is, to create a column containing all the debit, and another column containing all the credit.

My guess is that I have to create some kind of conditional column. In other words, I want to tell the computer: `"Create a column on dbo.asientti such that, if the value on "D/H" for amount x is "D", then x is inserted on the column"`. Then, I would do the same with `"H"` in order to have only the credit amounts.

That is, the debit amount on a new column D, and the credit amount H on another one.

Is there any way to do this on Transact SQL? I looked for information on conditional columns but I could not find anything.

Thanks in advance......

Comment: It's spelled **amount** - one "m" is *quite enough!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are [Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql#syntax).

For your example it would work somehow like this

(*Updated for new requirements - amount is your amount column):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.asientti
ADD 
D AS 
CASE WHEN DH = 'D' 
  THEN amount
  ELSE NULL
END,
H AS
CASE WHEN DH = 'C'
   THEN amount
   ELSE NULL
END
```